# StateListDrawable

Tags: android

I have a listView built in a ListActivity. I want the background of my rows to change when the item is pressed.

So I wrote in my ListActivity : this.getListView().setSelector(R.drawable.my_custom_selector);

This is my_custom_selector.xml :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/selector" />
</selector>
```

drawable/selector is a selector.9.png

The problem is that nothing happens.

BUT : when I replace this drawable with a color all of the screen gets this color when I press a row.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Wrong code for setSelector of ListviewItem. You must define a listviewItem in xml and setSelector of it, instead of setSelector of ListView

Answer (score 1):

Try to set your listview selector in .xml file 
for example in your listview

```
android:background="@drawable/your_selector"
```

[here](http://www.geekmind.net/2009/10/android-custom-listview-selector.html) a small but good tutorials, check it. It also help you to solve your problem.

Comment: I have no listview in xml. This is a ListActivity. (By the way you are right if I had a listview in my xml I could use ListSelector in my XML and it would work). So the only way, it seems, to have the listView is this.getListView() in the ListActivity

Comment: You can override onclick, onfocus methods to change background colors of list view.